# Will api.facebook.com end point be going away when 2.0 facebook api rolls out

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, backwards-compatibility

Ok so, Some confusion here, and perhaps I am just stupid.. perhaps somebody who works for Facebook even can answer I don't know...

It says FQL is going away when they phase version 1.0 out, ok fine and well.

Does that include only the graph.facebook end point?

What about api.Facebook end points, i see no mention of that there.... stuff that previously did not require a access token...

Really the simple question is: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,share_count,commentsbox_count,click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://www.microsoft.com%22

Would that still work in v2.0 or v2.1 seperately?

Thanks.

Comment: That is just another (outdated) way of making an FQL query – so you can be sure, this will not work any more as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API v2.0 was rolled out on April 30th 2014 already. The endpoint `api.facebook.com` is even older than Graph API v1.0, but apparently still supported, even with the Graph API v2.1. FQL itself will be available until August 6th 2016 with Graph API v2.0.

I just wouldn't rely on that, because it is long known that this endpoint is deprecated.

With Graph API v2.1, there's the new endpoint

```
/?id={url}
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/url/ Unfortunately, it has less details concerning the sharing information.